# How to convert normal sponge to chocolate sponge

Tags: cake, chocolate

I have a recipe for a normal Victoria sponge. I also have a huge box of Swiss hot chocolate powder. (The kind you sprinkle onto hot milk to make drinking chocolate.)

1. Is drinking chocolate a good way to add chocolate flavour to a cake? Or is that likely to not work?
2. How would I go about using it? Can I just add it, or do I need to adjust the other ingredients? How much should I use?

Comment: Do you mean Swiss chocolate? I thought Swizz might be a brand, but I can't find any reference to it.

Comment: @Jefromi I mean it's chocolate that I bought in Switzerland. You know, the country?

Comment: So yes, you mean Swiss.

Comment: *facepalm* I had no idea I am this dumb...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drinking chocolate isn't 'chocolatey' enough to make a chocolate cake. You need cocoa powder - replace 3 tablespoons of flour with it *et voila*, chocolate sponge.

Comment: Couldn't it work if you replace also some of the sugar in the recipe by more drinking chocolate powder?

Comment: @Mien Hot chocolate powder also usually has some kind of dry milk/creamer component, so it might not be that simple.

Comment: @Jefromi I meant the one you add to milk, not the one you add to water (since that last one contains milk powder). Or is there milk powder in both?

Comment: @Mien: Well, a lot of the main ones in the US say "add to milk or water" and have some milk powder, but yeah, I suppose there are some nicer ones that don't have milk in them.

Comment: This would be _so much easier_ if my helpful room mate hadn't thrown the packet away. :-P Then I might be able to read the ingredients list to you...

Comment: @Mien: Yeah, probably cultural. Given that this did actually come from Switzerland, I'm guessing it's without milk, but with sugar, so yes, you could probably reduce the sugar in the recipe, and add enough (that's the tricky part) chocolate powder. But you might as well just buy plain cocoa powder to bake with, and save this for drinking.

Comment: @mien no, you can't add this powder and less sugar. You need the sugar in a cake for creaming. You can't cream with the powdered sugar (which is more often than not dextrose instead of sucrose) in the chocolate drink powder.