# How should I convert my Victoria sponge to a chocolate sponge?

Tags: cake, chocolate, cupcakes, sponge-cake

I generally bake Victoria sponge cake with 6 oz flour. Now to make a chocolate sponge cake do I substitute 2 oz of flour with cocoa powder or do I keep the 6 oz flour and add additional 2 oz cocoa powder.

I have seen some recipes that mention the former and some recipes mention the latter of what I mentioned above. Which of these 2 methods is the best way to prepare a chocolate sponge cake.

Comment: Very, very closely related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/25136/how-to-convert-normal-sponge-to-chocolate-sponge?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Replace 2oz of flour with the cocoa powder. If you add an extra 2oz of dry ingredients, the ratio of wet to dry will be off and you will end up with a dry sponge.

Comment: One thing to bear in mind, if you are using self-raising flour in this recipe, you have also just removed 33% of your raising agent so you *could* end up with a flatter, denser sponge. You might need to add an additional raising agent such as bicarb to get round this.